# Mail in spam - spf is set

Tags: email, sendmail, spamassasin

I'm trying to send mails from my domain **tickety.be**. I'm using **sendmail** to do this.

My sender is info@tickety.be. My receiver is also info@tickety.be. My application is hosted on my Scaleway server. I've also setup cloudflare.

In my cloudflare settings I have:

[image]

But why is it going into spam?

Answer (score 0):

I would do the following things, they might not solve the issue completely but they will improve deliverability.

1. Make sure you have both forward (A) and reverse (PTR) records for your domain.
2. Send an email to your GMail account and check the headers ("Show original"), usually they include a lot of useful information ("PASS" is good).
3. Setup DKIM.
4. Try tools provided by http://mail-tester.com and https://www.port25.com/authentication-checker/
5. Check your IP using http://mxtoolbox.com. It should not be blacklisted.
6. Take a look at "Email Delivery for IT Professionals" by  MailChimp, it's a great and detailed guide.